# I need to get all data in list using linq and pass that list to anther linq query

Tags: c#, sql, list, linq

I have written a linq query to written the list of employee ids. So, I need to pass the list to another linq query to get the count of timesheets that they have submitted.

```SQL
SELECT UProj_UserID FROM UserProjects up
WHERE up.UProj_L1_ManagerId = 2240
OR up.UProj_L2_ManagerId = 2240 

SELECT COUNT(timesheetid) FROM timesheet
WHERE submittedtype = 1
AND userid in (2242,2244,2245,2246)
AND ApproverStatus = 1
```

These are the two SQL queries I had written to get employees under the managers
2.query to get the count of timesheets submitted by the employees.

```
var getempsformangrs = (from up in db.UserProjects
                        where up.UProj_L1_ManagerId == Mid || up.UProj_L2_ManagerId == Mid
                        select new DashboardMails
                        {
                            UProj_UserID = up.UProj_UserID
                        }).ToList();
```

Comment: Are 2242,2244,2245,2246 userids from the first query? If so, why can't you join the two queries together to get your result?

Comment: yes,but the managerids and employeeids are from same table(users)..if i join the queries i was not able to get the total rows count ..   select up.UProj_UserID,count(timesheetid) from UserProjects up
   join timesheet t on t.userid = up.uproj_userid
    where up.UProj_L1_ManagerId = 2240 OR up.UProj_L2_ManagerId=2240 and submittedtype = 1 and L1_ApproverStatus =1
 group by up.UProj_UserID,timesheetid.

Comment: Will this not give you what you want?    select count(t.timesheetid) from timesheet t
join UserProjects up on t.userid = up.UProj_UserID
and (up.UProj_L1_ManagerId = 2240 OR up.UProj_L2_ManagerId=2240)
where t.submittedtype = 1 and t.userid in (2242,2244,2245,2246) and t.ApproverStatus = 1